# How can i increase the width of this <td>?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, bootstrap-4

[image]

I want to increase the width of the marked td, i've tried increasing width on it but it doesn't do anything. I don't care if the content on the other cells get smaller even.

This table is inside a modal also.

Here's my code:

```
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Título</th>
            <th>Área</th>
            <th>Turno</th>
            <th>Horário</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Participantes</th>
            <th>Terceiros</th>
            <th>Quantidade na Área</th>
            <th>% Participação</th>
            <th>Ações</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(event, index) in selectedEvents" :key="event.id">
            <td v-if="!event.editing">{{ (event.theme) ? event.theme.title : '-' }}</td>
            <td v-if="event.editing" style="width: 500px">
                <v-select 
                :options="themes"
                label="title"
                :clearable="false"
                v-model="event.newTheme"
            ></v-select>            
            </td>
            <td>{{ (event.teams_shifts && event.teams_shifts.team.name) ? event.teams_shifts.team.name : 
                event.team.name ? event.team.name : '-' }}
            </td>
            . . .
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you try putting the width on the relevant `th` element?

Comment: Omg i'm actually dumb thank you very much